# address of opened file

Tags: c, file, file-descriptor

I would like to know the address of an opened file with open function:

```
int fd = open("file" , O_RONLY);
```

now we have the fd of this opened file, if we need to read from it, we just type:

```
read(fd, buffer, size);
```

**Example:**

```
file : | H | E | L | L | O |  | W | O | R | L | D |
```

if we read from that file 3 chars:

1. `int fd = open("file" , O_RONLY);`
2. `read(fd, buffer, 3);`

The cursor now here: | H | E | {L} | L | O |  | W | O | R | L          | D |

**Question:** So, how can I get the address of this `{L}` char, or the address of the first char `{H}`? I would like to know the address of this opened file without using the "FILE *F = fopen"**

Comment: What do you mean by “address”? The file read offset? If so, check out `lseek`.

Comment: A file doesn't have an address, so not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: I think you are making assumptions on how files work - and you should not. That is what the file operation functions are for. Whatever you try to do via that pointer, you need to find a way to do it via defined functions form libs.

Comment: If you have read 3 bytes from the file, the file pointer will now be at the *second* `L`, not the first.

Comment: Some of the file's data may not be in memory anywhere at all until you call a library function to access it. So there's no such thing as the address of those characters.

Comment: I suspect we are looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 4):

> i would like to know the address of this opened file without using the "FILE F = fopen"

There is no such thing. The file exists somewhere on disk, but it has no address in memory until you open and read some data from it.

What you do is `read` the contents of the file into some *buffer* which you provide. That buffer has an address. The address of the 3rd character in that buffer is `buffer+2`.

Comment: but if you open a file, the hole file load in RAM, to r/w from it.
so if i would like to save the first address how can i do ?
and thanks ^^

Comment: @alpha You have a totally wrong idea here. Opening a file does _not_ load it into memory.

Comment: yes sir i was wrong in this,
what i want to know, how to go back to the first character in the file after reading form it, without using lseek function

Comment: @alpha Please read http://xyproblem.info, then accept this answer and ask your _real_ question.

Comment: @alpha I don't know why you don't want to use `lseek`, but it is **the** way — the *only* way — to seek around in a file.  Why wouldn't you use it to do its job, if that's the job you need doing?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are making assumptions on how files work - and you should not. That is what the file operation functions are for. Whatever you try to do via that pointer, you need to find a way to do it via defined functions from libs.